# Agenda: Datos Personas

Tags: python-3.7

Estoy intentando programa una agenda donde pueda guardar diferentes datos, nombre,apellido,pueblo facturación etc...

Le estado dando vueltas pero siempre acabo en el mismo punto, voy introduciendo los datos de las personas uno a uno y los guardo en un fichero. Abro el fichero y veo que los datos están bien guardados. Luego para poder modificar esos datos lo que hago es abrir el fichero y guardarlos en un lista ( de esta forma todas las modificaciones que realizare los haré sobre la lista y luego actualizo el fichero).

El problema que tengo es que la lista siempre se me carga con los datos de la última persona del fichero. He intentado realizar los pasos uno a uno y voy leyendo todos los datos de las personas pero la ultima siempre me machaca todas las anteriores ¿¿??

Gracias

```
import io
import tkinter

#Importamos la clse Bezeroak de modulo creado por nosotros
#from Klase_Bezeroak import bezeroak


class interface:
def __init__(self,lista_clientes):
    self.lista_clientes=lista_clientes    

    #Programa para generar una ventana donde puedo introducir nombres y 
    datos
    #Crea una ventada de la clase TK
    self.ventana= tkinter.Tk()
    #Titulo de la Ventada
    self.ventana.title('Egurra')
    #Posicion y Tamaño
    self.ventana.geometry('400x400+600+100')
    #introducimos un widget
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='').pack()


    #Generamos un menu y la asociamos a la wich ventana
    self.menu = tkinter.Menu(self.ventana)

    #Generamos la pestaña de clientes y la primera opcion en la cascada
    self.pest_clientes = tkinter.Menu(self.menu)
    self.pest_clientes.add_command(label = 'Nuevo Cliente')

    #Generamos la segunda opcion dentro del Clientes
    self.pest_clientes.add_separator()
    self.pest_clientes.add_command(label = 'Ver Lista Clientes')

    #Generamos la tercera opcion dentro del Clientes
    self.pest_clientes.add_separator()
    self.pest_clientes.add_command(label = 'Buscar Cliente')

    #Generamos la cuarta opcion dentro del Clientes
    self.pest_clientes.add_separator()
    self.pest_clientes.add_command(label = 'Borrar Cliente')

    #Generamos la pestaña de consultas y la primera opcion en la cascada
    self.pest_consultas = tkinter.Menu(self.menu)
    self.pest_consultas.add_command(label = 'Facturacion')

    #Generamos la segunda opcion dentro del Consultas
    self.pest_consultas.add_separator()
    self.pest_consultas.add_command(label = 'Gastos')

    #Generamos la tercera opcion dentro del Consultas
    self.pest_consultas.add_separator()
    self.pest_consultas.add_command(label = 'Ordenar clientes por Gasto')

    #Generamos la cuarta opcion dentro del Consultas
    self.pest_consultas.add_separator()
    self.pest_consultas.add_command(label = 'Consumo de leña por medida')

    #Generamos la quinta opcion dentro del Consultas
    self.pest_consultas.add_separator()
    self.pest_consultas.add_command(label = 'Estado Almacen')


    self.menu.add_cascade(label = 'Clientes', menu = self.pest_clientes)
    self.menu.add_cascade(label = 'Consultas', menu = self.pest_consultas)

    self.ventana.config(menu = self.menu)



    izena_Var = tkinter.StringVar()
    abizena_Var = tkinter.StringVar()
    herria_Var = tkinter.StringVar()
    tlf_Var = tkinter.IntVar()
    neurria_Var = tkinter.IntVar()
    bidaiak_Var = tkinter.IntVar()
    prezioa_Var = tkinter.IntVar()
    fakturazioa_Var = tkinter.DoubleVar()
    self.num_lista_Var = tkinter.IntVar() 

    #Generamos la entrada de Izena
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='Izena').place(x=10,y=10)
    tkinter.Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=izena_Var, width=10).place(x=70,y=10)

    #Generamos la entrada de Abizena
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='Abizena'). place(x=140,y=10)
    tkinter.Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=abizena_Var, width=10).place(x=200,y=10)

    #Generamos la entrada de Herria
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='Herria').place(x=10,y=40)
    tkinter.Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=herria_Var, width=10).place(x=70,y=40)

    #Generamos la entrada de Telefonoa
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='Telefonoa').place(x=140,y=40)
    tkinter.Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=tlf_Var, width=10).place(x=200,y=40)

    #Generamos la entrada de Neurria
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='Neurria').place(x=10,y=70)
    tkinter.Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=neurria_Var, width=10).place(x=70,y=70)

    #Generamos la entrada de bidaiak
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='Bidaiak').place(x=140,y=70)
    tkinter.Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=bidaiak_Var, width=10).place(x=200,y=70)

    #Generamos la entrada de prezioa
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='Prezioa').place(x=10,y=100)
    tkinter.Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=prezioa_Var, width=10).place(x=70,y=100)

    #Generamos la entrada de Fakturazioa
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='Fakturazioa').place(x=140,y=100)
    tkinter.Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=fakturazioa_Var, width=10).place(x=200,y=100)

    #Imprimir un cliente
    tkinter.Label(self.ventana, text='Numero en la lista').place(x=80,y=300)
    tkinter.Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=self.num_lista_Var, width=10).place(x=200,y=300)
    tkinter.Button(self.ventana, text="Sakatu", command =self.escribir).place(x=250,y=300)




    #Creamos un tipo de dato bezeroak en la variable bezeroa
    self.bezeroa = bezeroak()
    self.bezeroa.izena = izena_Var
    self.bezeroa.abizena = abizena_Var
    self.bezeroa.herria = herria_Var
    self.bezeroa.tlf = tlf_Var
    self.bezeroa.neurria = neurria_Var
    self.bezeroa.bidaiak = bidaiak_Var
    self.bezeroa.prezioa = prezioa_Var
    self.bezeroa.fakturazioa = fakturazioa_Var

    tkinter.Button(self.ventana, text="Bezero Berria", command =self.crear_cliente).place(x=10,y=150)
    tkinter.Button(self.ventana, text="Datuak_Kargatu", command =self.cargar_datos).place(x=200,y=150)

    tkinter.Button(self.ventana, text="Gorde", command =self.Guardar).place(x=10,y=200)
    tkinter.Button(self.ventana, text="Irten", command=quit).place(x=200,y=200)

    self.ventana.mainloop()

####### Funcion  Escribir          #########################################################       
def escribir(self):
    print('Izena:',self.lista_clientes[0].izena)
    print('Abizena:',self.lista_clientes[0].abizena)
    print('Herria:',self.lista_clientes[0].herria)
    print('Telefonoa:',self.lista_clientes[0].tlf)
    print('Neurria',self.lista_clientes[0].neurria,'cm')
    print('Bidai Kopurua',self.lista_clientes[0].bidaiak)
    print('prezioa',self.lista_clientes[0].prezioa)
    print('Fakturazioa',self.lista_clientes[0].fakturazioa)

######## End Funcion Escribir     #########################################################


####### Funciona Guardar          ######################################################### 
def Guardar(self):
    if (self.pos_bezeroa == 0):        
            lineas = ""
    else:
            lineas = "\n"                

    Datos_Bezeroa =lineas+self.lista_clientes[self.pos_bezeroa].izena.get()+";"
    Datos_Bezeroa += self.lista_clientes[self.pos_bezeroa].abizena.get()+";"
    Datos_Bezeroa += self.lista_clientes[self.pos_bezeroa].herria.get()+";"
    Datos_Bezeroa += str(self.lista_clientes[self.pos_bezeroa].tlf.get())+";"
    Datos_Bezeroa += str(self.lista_clientes[self.pos_bezeroa].neurria.get())+";"
    Datos_Bezeroa += str(self.lista_clientes[self.pos_bezeroa].bidaiak.get())+";"
    Datos_Bezeroa += str(self.lista_clientes[self.pos_bezeroa].prezioa.get())+";"
    Datos_Bezeroa += str(self.lista_clientes[self.pos_bezeroa].fakturazioa.get())+";" #Añadimos el "end" como final de datos del cliente

    archivo=io.open('Log_Datos.ods','a')
    archivo.write(Datos_Bezeroa)
    archivo.close()
######## End funcion Guardar       #########################################################

####### Funciona Crear Cliente     #########################################################
def crear_cliente(self):
    self.lista_clientes.append(self.bezeroa)
    print (len(self.lista_clientes))
    self.pos_bezeroa=len(self.lista_clientes)-1
    print (self.pos_bezeroa)
    self.Guardar()
######## End funcion Crear Cliente #########################################################

######## Funciona Cargar Datos     #########################################################
def cargar_datos(self):
    ######## Abrir tranferir a Datos_clientes y cerrar archivo#######################################
    #        Lo leemos con redlines y nos devuelve una lista                                #
    archivo=io.open('Log_Datos.ods','r')
    datos_clientes=archivo.readlines()
    archivo.close()

    print (datos_clientes)
    i=0

     ######## Bucle While #############################################################################

    while i < len(datos_clientes):
            var_clientes             = datos_clientes[i].split(";")
            self.lista_clientes.append(self.bezeroa)       
            self.lista_clientes[i].izena       = var_clientes[0]
            self.lista_clientes[i].abizena     = var_clientes[1]
            self.lista_clientes[i].herria      = var_clientes[2]
            self.lista_clientes[i].tlf         = var_clientes[3]
            self.lista_clientes[i].neurria     = var_clientes[4]
            self.lista_clientes[i].bidaiak     = var_clientes[5]
            self.lista_clientes[i].prezioa     = var_clientes[6]
            self.lista_clientes[i].fakturazioa = var_clientes[7]             
            print (self.lista_clientes[i].izena)
            print (self.lista_clientes[i].abizena)
            print (self.lista_clientes[i].herria)
            print (self.lista_clientes[i].tlf)
            print (self.lista_clientes[i].neurria)
            print (self.lista_clientes[i].bidaiak)
            print (self.lista_clientes[i].prezioa)
            print (self.lista_clientes[i].fakturazioa)

            if i>=1 :                        
                    print (self.lista_clientes[i-1].izena)
                    print (self.lista_clientes[i-1].abizena)
                    print (self.lista_clientes[i-1].herria)
                    print (self.lista_clientes[i-1].tlf)
                    print (self.lista_clientes[i-1].neurria)
                    print (self.lista_clientes[i-1].bidaiak)
                    print (self.lista_clientes[i-1].prezioa)
                    print (self.lista_clientes[i-1].fakturazioa)

            i=i+1

    ######## Fin Bucle While
    ######## #############################################################################

    print (self.lista_clientes[1].izena)
    print(self.lista_clientes[1].abizena)
    print(self.lista_clientes[1].herria)
    print(self.lista_clientes[1].tlf)
    print(self.lista_clientes[1].neurria)
    print(self.lista_clientes[1].bidaiak)
    print(self.lista_clientes[1].prezioa)
    print(self.lista_clientes[1].fakturazioa)
    print('longitud listabezeroak', len(self.lista_clientes))

    ######## End funcion cargar datos #########################################################

def main():
    lista_clientes=[]
    mi_app = interface(lista_clientes)
    return 0

if __name__ == 'main':
 main()
```

Comment: Gracias Jose he estado haciendo pruebas y funciona. En todas las pruebas que hacia siempre me tropezaba con la misma piedra.

Comment: Entonces la respuesta que te di era correcta? Acéptala entonces para que no salte de nuevo de aquí a un tiempo por el bot de la comunidad. [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no me equivoco el fallo lo tienes en que recorres un bucle modificando la lista y el orden lo descolocas en `while i < len(datos_clientes):`. Cuando ejecutas el `append()` al principio del bucle estás añadiendo un elemento nuevo a la lista y cuando accedes a la lista por el indice 'i' estás accediendo al elemento anterior y es cuando empiezan a ocurrir cosas malas, vives en pecado y te mereces todo lo que te pase. :) Solo se ejecuta 'append()' cuando quieres añadir un elemento a una lista, no para generar un elemento vacío al que llenar. (Se puede, pero ensucia el código e ineficiente porque luego tendrás que volver a recorrer la lista para llenar los huecos y recorrer una lista mientras la modificas es la receta para el desastre)

No se si funcionará, pero puedes probar con esto:

```
for cliente in datos_clientes:
    var_clientes = cliente.split(";")
    cliente_temp = bezeroak()
    cliente_temp.izena = var_clientes[0]
    cliente_temp.izena.abizena = var_clientes[1]
    cliente_temp.izena.herria = var_clientes[2]
    cliente_temp.izena.tlf = var_clientes[3]
    cliente_temp.izena.neurria = var_clientes[4]
    cliente_temp.izena.bidaiak = var_clientes[5]
    cliente_temp.izena.prezioa = var_clientes[6]
    cliente_temp.izena.fakturazioa = var_clientes[7]
    self.lista_clientes.append(cliente_temp)
```

### ¿POR QUÉ?

Es un error común cuando empiezas a programar en Python a usar los mismos modismos cuando vienes de otros lenguajes, o pasar por alto "trampas" cuando la intuición nos engaña.

Una forma más elegante y correcta en Python de recorrer una lista es usar un bucle `for` que es un poco diferente de C. Lo que ocurre cuando ejecutas `for cliente in datos_clientes:` es que se genera un bucle con la cantidad exacta de elementos (es un `len(datos_clientes)` a escondidas) y inicializa la variable *cliente* con el valor de "datos_cliente[i]" donde **i** es cada uno de los pasos del bucle (todo entre bambalinas). La magia es que Python lleva el control por ti y simplifica el código para ahorrarte disgustos.

Además es muy flexible, porque si por ejemplo necesitas el índice para otro propósito puedes utilizar la funcion `enumerate()` y te devuelve tanto el valor posicional de la lista como el contenido de esa posición:

```
for indice, cliente in enumerate(datos_clientes):
    f'Cliente {indice}: {cliente.nombre}'
```

En ese bucle se asigna ambas variables *indice* y *cliente* al mismo tiempo con el resultado de `enumerate()` y de datos_clientes_

También puedes usar otros trucos, como recorrer dos listas al mismo tiempo con la funcion `zip()`:

```
for cliente_a, cliente_b in zip(datos_clientes_a, datos_clientes_b):
    f'Nombres: {cliente_a.nombre}, {cliente_b.nombre}'
```

Y si quieres piruetas encapsulas `enumerate()` también:

```
for indice, cliente_a, cliente_b in enumerate(zip(datos_clientes_a, datos_clientes_b)):
    f'[{indice} - Nombres: {cliente_a.nombre}, {cliente_b.nombre}'
```

Entenderás que un bucle "while()" tiene un proposito muy particular y especifico y que en la mayoria de casos un for será lo más adecuado.

Si tienes más dudas abre otra pregunta y te intentaremos ayudar.